# Promoting org mode headings in a region with a numeric prefix

Tags: org-mode, region

Suppose I have a few org mode headings I would like to promote a few times

```
* Heading 1
* Heading 2
```

If I only wanted to demote these headings once, I could select both in a region and call `org-metaright` with the keybinding `M-<right>`. However, this deactivates the region so I cannot demote these headings multiple times without selecting everything again.

I tried supplying a numeric prefix to this command, but that did not do anything. This is because `org-metaright` does not use a numeric prefix.

Is there any way of doing exactly what I describe? I want to be able to select both headings in the example block and with one command (possibly with a numeric prefix) demote these headings multiple times at once. I am reasonably proficient with elisp and so could in theory write this code myself, but I want to make sure I am not missing something first.

Comment: The code in current upstream does not deactivate the region any longer - see commit [c8a5fef91065259c08aedcc8958568c0c7d47e1a](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=c8a5fef91065259c08aedcc8958568c0c7d47e1a) and the [description](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/diff/etc/ORG-NEWS?id=c8a5fef91065259c08aedcc8958568c0c7d47e1a) in the ORG-NEWS file. This will go into release 9.7.

Comment: Indeed, this is true; I have just tested this for myself. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question, NickD is correct. The code in current upstream allows you to invoke commands <kbd>M-<right></kbd>, <kbd>M-<left></kbd>, <kbd>M-<up></kbd>, <kbd>M-<down></kbd> without deactivating the current region (see [ORG-NEWS](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/diff/etc/ORG-NEWS?id=c8a5fef91065259c08aedcc8958568c0c7d47e1a)). It's not quite passing a numeric prefix to promote or demote but it's probably close enough for most people.

To allow these keyboard shortcuts to promote/demote headings multiple times with a numeric prefix you need to advise `org-do-demote` and `org-do-promote`, which are called by <kbd>M-<right></kbd> and <kbd>M-<left></kbd> respectively when the point is on a heading. The following code works for me with upstream org and so org versions >=9.7.

```el
(defun make-repeatable (orig-fun &optional n)
  "Take an interactive function `orig-fun' that does not accept a numeric prefix, and advise it to accept a numeric prefix by simply calling the function `n' times."
  (interactive "p")
  (dotimes (i (max n 1))
    (call-interactively orig-fun)))
(advice-add 'org-do-demote :around #'make-repeatable)
(advice-add 'org-do-promote :around #'make-repeatable)
```